# Looking compare data based on dates in SQL to then run in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, compare

[image: screenshot]

HI
I have created a piece of sql below to allow me to compare if a customer had stock in a previous period or not, i need to show where the customer has stock in this period and not the last period
Simply i want to be able to run a report that only lists PERIOD3 CUSTOMER1, even if i specify dates which include periods 1 - 4

```
PERIOD1 CUSTOMER1
PERIOD2 NULL
PERIOD3 CUSTOMER1
PERIOD4 CUSTOMER1
```

I dont know how in a report to only bring back PERIOD3 CUSTOMER1 data, what is the best way to do this? in an SSRS report or in the original SQL which can then be added to a SSRS report

```
SELECT  C43.ACCOUNT15_C43, 
        C43.RECODATE_C43, 
        SNAPSHOT.WORDREF1_C43, 
        CUSTOMER.NADNAME, 
        CUSTOMER.NADPOCODE, 
        CUSTOMER.ATTVALFROM_T10
FROM     
    (
        SELECT  ACCOUNT15_C43, 
                RECODATE_C43
        FROM      dbo.MBC430
        GROUP BY 
                ACCOUNT15_C43, 
                RECODATE_C43
    ) AS C43 
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  dbo.MAA930.ACCOUNT15_NAD, 
                dbo.MAA930.NADACCNO, 
                dbo.MAA930.NADNAME, 
                dbo.MAA930.NADPOCODE, 
                T10.ATTVALFROM_T10
        FROM dbo.MAA930 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  ACCOUNT15_T10, 
                        CUSTOMERLONG_T10, 
                        ATTVALFROM_T10
                FROM     
                dbo.MBT100
                WHERE ATTRIBCODE_T10 = 'CU1'
            ) AS T10 
            ON dbo.MAA930.ACCOUNT15_NAD = T10.ACCOUNT15_T10 
            AND dbo.MAA930.NADACCNO = T10.CUSTOMERLONG_T10
        WHERE dbo.MAA930.NADSEQNO = '999' 
        AND dbo.MAA930.NADTYPE = '23'
    ) AS CUSTOMER 
    ON C43.ACCOUNT15_C43 = CUSTOMER.ACCOUNT15_NAD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  MBC430_1.RECODATE_C43, 
                MBC430_1.WORDREF1_C43
        FROM     dbo.MBB010 
        INNER JOIN dbo.MBC430 AS MBC430_1 
            ON dbo.MBB010.PARTNO = MBC430_1.PARTNO_C43 
            AND dbo.MBB010.ACCOUNT15 = MBC430_1.ACCOUNT15_C43
        GROUP BY 
            dbo.MBB010.PRE_B01, 
            dbo.MBB010.PARTYPE, 
            MBC430_1.WORDREF1_C43, 
            MBC430_1.RECODATE_C43
        HAVING dbo.MBB010.PRE_B01 = 'T' 
        AND dbo.MBB010.PARTYPE = 'FG'
        AND NOT MBC430_1.WORDREF1_C43 = ' '
    ) AS SNAPSHOT 
    ON CUSTOMER.NADACCNO = SNAPSHOT.WORDREF1_C43 
    AND C43.RECODATE_C43 = SNAPSHOT.RECODATE_C43
```

Thanks

Comment: Heavy lifting should be handled in the SQL, not in SSRS. Use SSRS for quick agregation of limited data and making things look pretty

Comment: Good grief your script here is a mess.  Please post your source table structure with some dummy data and your desired output and you may be able to get some assistance.

Comment: You are talking about periods and customers. How does this relate to the query you posted? Also: If your query already allows to determine whether a customer has stock in the previous period, just use your query to define your dataset, adding a where clause to show only those records you are interested in.